# How to handle Ajax post requests in a Wordpress plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out how Ajax and Wordpress plugins work, but it seems to be pretty badly documented. Ideally what I want is:

- The plugin gets it own Ajax url to use, this is defined globally.
- The plugin can handle Ajax requests

I understand that there are two actions that are used for this. One for logged in users and one for users without an account or privileges. However, I just want to create an Ajax endpoint for a form.

I'm not looking for code snippets, just need to be pointed in the write direction as to Wordpress Plugins and Ajax handling.

Comment: Since wordpress 4.4 the rest api is included, so you can create a cusom endpoint for your plugin and use that: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Comment: Thanks. I knew there was a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented below own AJAX functionality in functions.php, Just try this in plugin,

**functions.php :**

```
function prefix_ajax_delete_search() {
    global $wpdb;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $wpdb->delete('sf_save_search', array('id' => $_POST['tid']) ); 
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_delete_search', 'prefix_ajax_delete_search' );
```

**Script.js:**

```
function deleteSearch( tid) {
    var url = window.location.href;

    jQuery.post(
        ajaxurl, 
        {
            'action': 'delete_search',
            'tid':   tid,
        },
        function(response){
          location.reload();
        }
    );
}
```