# JSON.parse single variable - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I started with Ajax and unfortunately I have a problem with JSON.parse(). I want to pass a variable by click.

So far I have not found an answer to my specific problem. Maybe someone here can help me.

Errormessage:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 68
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.<anonymous> (ajax.js?ver=5.3.2:13)
at c (jquery.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
at l (jquery.js:2)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:2)
```

My JS-function: /admin/script/ajax.js

```
    $("#make").change(function(){

        var make = $('#make').val();
        console.log('Select Value hat sich geändert zu ' + make);

        $.ajax({
                url: wpAjax.ajaxUrl,
                data: 'make=' + make,
                type: 'post'
            }).done(function(model){
            model = JSON.parse(model);   // Here comes the error.
        })
    })
})
```

My PHP-Function: admin/script/filter.php

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['make'])) {
     $model = 'Model S';
     echo json_encode($model);
  }
?>
```

Wordpress functions.php in theme

```
function my_enqueue() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin/script/ajax.js', array('jquery') );

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'wpAjax',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );

get_template_part( 'admin/script/filter');
```

Comment: Check the response from your script with `console.log(model);` or check in your Network tab of the Developer Console. You're not getting a proper JSON from the server. It could be an error or something else.

Comment: Is your JSON actually, clean JSON? Is your JSON empty?

Comment: console.log(model) first to see the initial data; and how you need to handle it, you may not need to do a parse

Comment: @emilioestevez — It certainly isn't empty. It has a `<` at position 68.

Comment: Pls show full code of php. it seems to send redundant data in response

Comment: I edited my post with the code.

Comment: console.log(model) give me the variable, but also the the complete html of my page.

Comment: @ril09376 — Well, that's the problem then. Why are you loading the JSON into a template?

Comment: Excuse me, how do you I to load it properly? I'm still quite a beginner and very grateful for tips.

Comment: Possible dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44495497/how-to-handle-ajax-post-requests-in-a-wordpress-plugin (I don't know, I only briefly tried doing development in WordPress before deciding it was not for me)

Answer (score 0):

Once you use wordpress, first you need is to bind php function to action

Say the action name is `get_model`

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_model', 'my_func' ); // Here action name tied to function
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_model', 'my_func' ); // Here too for unregistered users

function my_func(){
    if(isset($_POST['make'])) {
        $model = 'Model S';
        echo json_encode($model);
    } else {
        die('No models');
    }
}
```

then you need to define action name as ajax parameter in javascript

```
$("#make").change(function(){
    var make = $('#make').val();
    console.log('Select Value hat sich geändert zu ' + make);
    $.ajax({
            url: wpAjax.ajaxUrl,
            data: {
                  'make': make,
                   action: 'get_model'},  // add action name here
            type: 'post'
        }).done(function(model){
        model = JSON.parse(model);   // Here comes the error.
    })
})
```

And now I suspect it has to work well. Please test

You can watch post parameters in browser dev console
[image]

Once it fails, you can find a real response conrtent in "Preview" and "Response" tabs in dev console (switch on "XHR" filter before)

[image]

Comment: I just copied your code and put the jquery inside $(document).ready(function(){....}) and put your first code in functions.php and deleted my "get_template_part( 'admin/script/filter');" from the functions.php. But still get an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0. If i watch dev console, there is no Form Data.

Comment: I can add that its working until "model = JSON.parse(model);".

Comment: it's because wrong response comes. Inspect your functions.php - it might have redundant output, just smth like `include file.php`, which echoes html, either there's a kind of syntax error in functions.php

Comment: I've added another picture to answer. Have a look

Comment: Ok i found the Form Data. For some reason the file isn't ajax.php rather my pages name. This is my functions.php https://pastebin.com/ddxxXPCR

Comment: It's unclear why do you use `get_template_part` in functions.php. Don't you mind to do that in header or inside of any template? Essentially functions.php shouldnt generate any direct output. You should wrap any output into function and then call it on demand

Comment: I used them to make the functions clearer. They include things such as to register post types. How else can you best split the functions?

Comment: If i change url: "wpAjax.ajaxUrl" to "wpAjax.ajax_url" it's giving me the admin-ajax.php. Now it's working.